# Overriding Symfony Request Class - Where to place the override code?

Tags: php, symfony, request

Symfony has a pretty clear code example on how to override the request class, but I do not know where in my App I should place it. I receive the request object from Symfony in my controller actions and want to get the SpecialRequest Object instead.

I already tried a kernel.request listener, but this seems to be too late. Is there a place where this kind of initialization code would fit?

```
Request::setFactory(function (
    array $query = array(),
    array $request = array(),
    array $attributes = array(),
    array $cookies = array(),
    array $files = array(),
    array $server = array(),
    $content = null
) {
    return SpecialRequest::create(
        $query,
        $request,
        $attributes,
        $cookies,
        $files,
        $server,
        $content
    );
});
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#overriding-the-request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example given, the `Request::setFactory` method is called immediately prior to calling the `Request::createFromGlobals` method. This would imply that the appropriate place for calling this method would be in the front controller, e.g. app.php, app_dev.php and any other file used as a front controller.

In fact the `Request::createFromGlobals` method and the `Request::create` method check to see whether a callable has been set by the `Request::setFactory` method, and if so they use this callable to create an object that should extend the Request class.